# How to replay or manually send an email through my MTA

Tags: smtp, mta

I have a dynamic email analysis engine (a glorified MTA) that detects malicious content.  I recently had an email get through without being detected.  We (meaning out vendor) made some adjustments to the system and now I find myself needing to replay the original email through the MTA to see if it is detected.

Does anyone know how to manually 'replay' the original email without configuring a new MTA to send the email, and if not, is there a lightweight MTA that I can easily configure to function as a bare-bones client for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/):

```
swaks --server foo.example.com --tls --data mymessage.eml
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! I also came across a nice python script here: https://gist.github.com/sosukeinu/4370139#file-send-message-py